# Erro - "Campo obrigatório" em upload de imagem utilizando Django

Tags: python, django, aplicação-web

Gente, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com django e após organizar o formulário fui testar o cadastro e o campo de upload de imagem sempre apresenta a mesma mensagem: "Campo obrigatório" não importa qual tipo de foto eu tente upar. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

**formFuncionario.html:**

```
{% extends 'aplicacao/base.html' %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy}}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Salvar Funcionário</button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**models.py:**

```
class Funcionario(models.Model):
     nome = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     data_nascimento = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
     endereco = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     telefone = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     #relacionamento 1 para n(um depratamento tem vários funcionarios) (1 ou muitos funcionarios pertencem a 1 dep)
     departamento = models.ForeignKey(Departamento, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     estado_civil = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     cpf = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     salario = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=4)
     image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/images/', height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=100, null='true')
     

     class Meta:
         verbose_name_plural = 'Funcionarios'#difinir o nome em plural da entidade funcionario

    
     def __str__(self):
         return self.nome
```

**form.py:**

```
class FuncionarioForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Funcionario
        fields = ['nome', 'data_nascimento', 'endereco' , 'telefone', 'departamento', 'estado_civil' , 'email', 'cpf' , 'salario', 'image']
```

**views.py:**

```
class FuncionarioCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Funcionario
    fields = ('nome', 'data_nascimento', 'endereco', 'telefone', 'departamento', 'estado_civil', 'email', 'cpf', 'salario','image')
    template_name = 'aplicacao/formFuncionario.html'
```

Answer (score 1):

Viva, eu diria que o problema será na forma como estás a definir o Null. Define antes assim. Qual a versão de Django estás a utilizar? Uma nota, os parâmetros definidos com 'None' são desnecessários, não os coloquei no exemplo abaixo.

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/images/', max_length=100, null=True)
```

Outra opção, não funcionando a anterior. Utiliza um default, é o que faço sempre. Assim mostro uma imagem enquanto não é feito o upload de uma, para a maioria dos casos serve.

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/images/', max_length=100, default='images/profile/avatar-default-icon.png')
```